# Filtered summary and details after a pivotable

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I promise I googled that - I guess I am taking the wrong approach from the beginning, so...

Let's assume I have a dataframe with many `parts` which have undergone a few `checks` and are to be delivered in a few `orders`.

I struggle to find a way to list all orders with parts for which 100% or more than 50% of the checks have passed ....

What I mean :

```
import pandas as  pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'order' : ['order_A',   'order_A',  'order_A',  'order_A',  'order_B',  'order_B',  'order_B' ],
    'part'  : ['part_1',    'part_1',   'part_2',   'part_2',   'Part_3',   'Part_3',   'Part_3', ],
    'check' : ['passed',    'passed',   'failed',   'failed',   'failed',   'failed',   'passed'    ],   
     })

pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    data = df, 
    index = ['part'], 
    columns = ['check'], 
    aggfunc = 'count',
    fill_value = pd.NA ,
    margins = True)

percent_pivot = pivot.div( pivot.iloc[:,-1], axis=0 )
```

the raw data is pretty basic here, there are many order and many part is the actual dataset   :

```
     order    part   check
0  order_A  part_1  passed
1  order_A  part_1  passed
2  order_A  part_2  failed
3  order_A  part_2  failed
4  order_B  Part_3  failed
5  order_B  Part_3  failed
6  order_B  Part_3  passed
```

the list pivot table, which I think is half-way from want I am looking for, is  :

```
           order               
check     failed    passed  All
part                           
Part_3  0.666667  0.333333  1.0
part_1      <NA>         1  1.0
part_2         1      <NA>  1.0
All     0.571429  0.428571  1.0
```

**how can I get back the list of `parts` with passed = 1?** ( part_1 here as all tests passed ) ?

**how can I get back the list of `parts` with passed > 50 % ?** (part_3 here )

stretch goal : get the `order` of the parts ...

I guess the root cause of my failure is that I do not manage to filter the pivot table as if it were a 'regular' dataframe ( I guess a fail to grasp multiindex, don't I ? )

Answer (score 1):

You try:

```
pivot.div(pivot[('order','All')], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
           order               
check     failed    passed  All
part                           
Part_3  0.666667  0.333333  1.0
part_1      <NA>         1  1.0
part_2         1      <NA>  1.0
All     0.571429  0.428571  1.0
```

To get a list of all parts that past 100 %:

```
percent_pivot.index[np.where(percent_pivot[('order','passed')] == 1)].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['part_1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of Scott's answer, after you get his output `pivot`, you can call

```
pivot[pivot['order','passed']==1].index
```

To get the `parts` a.k.a indices that have `passed==1`. Output:

```
Index(['part_1'], dtype='object', name='part')
```

You can do something similar for percentages depending on how you do you calculations, but you should modify the boolean to use `np.isclose` to cover for floating point errors (see python floating point errors [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)). For example:

```
pivot[
    np.isclose(pivot['order','passed'].fillna(0),1/3)
].index
```

output:

```
Index(['Part_3'], dtype='object', name='part')
```